# Django capture traces of Open Telemetry

Tags: python, django, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am a newbie to Open Telemetry and trying to see how traces are captured for a Django app. I am assuming that OTel should be able to provide traces of all invoked functions for a particular Django Request.
E.g.I have a very basic Django app with a views.py as

```
def log_console():
    print("Print in terminal")

def show_date():
    now = datetime.now()
    log_console()
    return HTMLResponse()
```

The url is configured to serve `show_date`

My expectation js that when I configure `manage.py` with `DjangoInstrumentor().instrument()`

In the console I should be able to see reference to the function `log_console` as it is invoked when serving the `show_date`

But cant see any reference to log_console, not sure if this is a valid use case for Tracing in Open Telemetry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OTel](https://opentelemetry.io/) would not instrument all functions by default (like your `log_console()` and `show_date()` from your `view.py`): you need to explicitly instrument the functions you want to capture traces from.

```bash
+-------------------+       +---------------+      +-------------------+
| Django Application | ---> | show_date URL | ---> | show_date() View  |
+-------------------+       +---------------+      +-------------------+
  |                                                         |
  | OTel Instrumentation                                    V
  |                                                     +-------------+
  +---------------------------------------------------->| log_console |
                                                        +-------------+
                                                        | OTel Span   |
                                                        +-------------+
```

That would involve a [`Tracer`](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/signals/traces/#tracer) and a [`TracerProvider`](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/signals/traces/#tracer-provider):

```py
from opentelemetry.sdk import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import Tracer

tracer_provider = TracerProvider()
tracer = tracer_provider.get_tracer(__name__)

def log_console():
    print("Print in terminal")

    with tracer.start_as_current_span("log_console"):
        log_console()
```

That will create a Tracer object and inject it into the `log_console()` function. When the `log_console()` function is called, a new trace will be created and the `log_console()` function will be recorded as a child of that trace. That will make sure the `log_console()` function is included in the traces when they are captured using OpenTelemetry.

You need configure the Django app to use OpenTelemetry (see "[OpenTelemetry Python / Django Instrumentation](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/django/README.html)"):

```py
from django.core.management import get_commands

from opentelemetry.django.instrumentation import DjangoInstrumentor


def instrument():
    DjangoInstrumentor().instrument()


def uninstrument():
    DjangoInstrumentor().uninstrument()


get_commands().register('django-instrument', instrument)
get_commands().register('django-uninstrument', uninstrument)
```

That does add two new commands to the [Django management command interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/): `django-instrument` and `django-uninstrument`.
These commands (`python manage.py django-instrument` / `python manage.py django-uninstrument`) can be used to enable and disable OpenTelemetry instrumentation for the Django app.

---

Once the app is instrumented, the traces can be captured using an OpenTelemetry exporter.
For example, this would capture the traces and send them to a Jaeger instance (distributed tracing backend) running on `localhost:9411`:

```py
from opentelemetry.exporters import jaeger

exporter = jaeger.JaegerExporter(config=jaeger.Config(agent_address="localhost:9411"))

tracer_provider = TracerProvider()
tracer_provider.add_span_processor(exporter.add_span_processor())

tracer = tracer_provider.get_tracer(__name__)

with tracer.start_span("request"):
    # handle the request
```

That code will create a [Jaeger exporter](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exporter/jaeger/jaeger.html?highlight=JaegerExporter) and add it to the `TracerProvider`. The `TracerProvider` will then use the exporter to capture all of the traces generated by the app. The traces will be sent to the Jaeger instance running on `localhost:9411`.

---

> Is it possible to trace without adding the `with tracer.start_as_current_span("log_console")`? (as I have many places and adding these lines in the code will not be an option)

Not really.

For functions that you specifically want to trace and which are not covered by automatic instrumentation, you could create a [custom decorator that starts and ends a span](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/python/manual/#creating-spans-with-decorators). That approach still requires modification of your code, but is more concise than adding tracing code manually to each function.

```py
from functools import wraps
from opentelemetry import trace

def trace_function(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
        with tracer.start_as_current_span(func.__name__):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@trace_function
def your_function():
    # your code
```

Another more advanced and less common approach in Python is using aspect-oriented programming to intercept function calls and add tracing. That is more complex and might involve using additional libraries like [`aspectlib`](https://pypi.org/project/aspectlib/). That method allows adding tracing to functions without modifying their code directly but adds complexity to the application.

Finally, as an alternative, for Django applications, much of the tracing can be accomplished via [**middleware**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/middleware/) that intercepts HTTP requests. That will not trace every function call, but it will provide traces for each request and its processing lifecycle within Django.

Your Django project's file structure might look something like this:

```
your_django_project/
│
├── your_django_app/                          # Your Django application directory
│   ├── __init__.py                           # Initialization file for the app
│   ├── views.py                              # Views for your Django app
│   ├── models.py                             # Models for your Django app
│   ├── urls.py                               # URL configurations for your app
│   ├── tracing_middleware.py  <=====         # Custom middleware for tracing
│   └── ...                                   # Other files (admin.py, tests.py, etc.)
│
├── your_django_project/                      # Your Django project directory
│   ├── __init__.py                           # Initialization file for the project
│   ├── settings.py            <=====         # Settings/configuration for your project
│   ├── urls.py                               # Root URL configurations for your project
│   ├── wsgi.py                               # WSGI configuration for deployment
│   └── ...                                   # Other project-level files
│
├── manage.py                                 # Management script for Django
└── ...                                       # Other files (requirements.txt, etc.)
```

Create a new file `tracing_middleware.py` in your Django app folder:

```py
# your_django_app/tracing_middleware.py

from opentelemetry import trace

class TracingMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self.tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Start a new span for this request
        with self.tracer.start_as_current_span("http_request"):
            # Process the request
            response = self.get_response(request)
            return response
```

That file contains the `TracingMiddleware` class, which uses OpenTelemetry's tracer to start a new span for each HTTP request.
When a request is made, the middleware creates a span, processes the request, and then ends the span when the response is sent.

And in your `settings.py`, add the new `TracingMiddleware` to the `MIDDLEWARE` list:

```py
# your_django_project/settings.py

# Add 'your_django_app.tracing_middleware.TracingMiddleware' to your MIDDLEWARE list
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # other middleware classes 
    'your_django_app.tracing_middleware.TracingMiddleware',
]
```

By adding `TracingMiddleware` to the `MIDDLEWARE` list in Django's settings, you make sure this middleware is applied to every request handled by your Django application.

Comment: Thanks for your response, is it possible to trace without adding the ```with tracer.start_as_current_span("log_console")``` as I have a lot of places and adding these lines in the code will not be an option.

Comment: @HD I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, I think I will explore via Django Middleware route for every request.

Comment: @HD OK, good call. I have rewritten the end of the answer to detail what the "Django Middleware route for every request" option could look like.